# Java Concurrency: Shared Memory Between Threads

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton

Suppose I have a Singleton class (any class can get the instance):

```
class data
{
      Color sun = "WHITE";
      String luminance = "HIGH";
      int age = 25;
      double speed = 52.5
      ...
}
```

Suppose I have several threads that get a reference to the Singleton instance of this class.  I'm trying to figure out a way to synchronize gets/sets on a PER FIELD basis.

If I have a synchronized getter/setter method for each variable, then this will basically "lock" the whole class(instead of the individual field) until that method is set.

Is there a way so that these threads only lock instance values instead of locking the whole class?

-- EDIT: I apologize for the huge one object data.

data is actually stored in several classes.  At most each object has only 20-25 members.

Comment: I think my head is going to explode. Can you not just reduce mutability? E.g. *remove* the need to lock-huge-monolithic-icky-object.

Comment: My face has melted off thinking about this.

Comment: Have you determined that there is a performance bottle neck if you do share one lock? Note you can lock an object 1000 times across multiple threads in about 2 ms. Basically before you make your application even more compilated, have you measured this bottleneck or are you guessing?

Comment: I weep for somebody who's going to inherit this class for maintenance.

Comment: You have a single class maintaining 1000 unrelated global mutable variables. And you are worried about concurrent performance?

Comment: I apologize.  data is actually spread through several classes.  And when I say many threads, I meant to say (at most maybe 2 or 3).  I thought generalizing it to "many" would create a general good programming practice for all cases.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey : I am only assuming that such a behemoth would become a bottleneck.  I only ask this question based on principle rather than practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **If I have a synchronized getter/setter method for each variable, then this will basically "lock" the whole class(instead of the individual field) until that method is set.**

Well, no. It will lock the whole object, but that's probably what you meant anyway...

> **data has 1000+ variables ...**

**Option 1**

If you have enough memory, you could simply have an `Object[] locks = new Object[1000];` for which you acquire the locks on.

```
public void setColor(Color newCol) {
    synchronized (locks[17]) {
        sun = newCol;
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Another option may be to mark all fields as `volatile`. This will at least make sure that the reads and writes are atomically performed.

**Option 3**

Have a look at `AtomicLong`, `AtomicReference`, `AtomicBoolean`, ... and so on in the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).